# assign a factor level based on closely matching values in 2 numerical vectors (coordinates)

Tags: r, vector, coordinates, match

I have a list of reference coordinates in a dataframe that locate colonies on a 2d surface:

```
colonies <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
x_ref <- c(1206, 870, 1932, 57)
y_ref <- c(6631, 157, 6510, 329)

ref.df <- cbind(colonies, x_ref, y_ref)
```

I have a second dataframe with serial observations of the 2d surface: there are x and y coordinates for observed colonies, and I need to assign the colony names to the correct rows of this df. BUT the coordinates might be slightly out, so I need to have a tolerance value built in, AND there will be multiple observations of the same colony.

So if there is a row with x == 1226 and y == 6652 I would want that row to be labelled "a", and a later row with x==1197 and y==6593 also to get assigned "a", while a row with x==1208 and y==3451 would be assigned NA as it isn't a close match to any colony in the reference dataframe. Ideally I would like to be able to control the 'tolerance' value.

All the functions in R I have found searching have not allowed this tolerance for slight errors in the observed coordinates (eg &in% doesn't). I can see how I would use a for loop and if / else to compare one value to all values in a vector +/- error , but not a vector of values, and for both x and y.

Sorry for long post.

========================================================================

Comment: have a look at `?cut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to calculate the distances yourself.

```
#First, a data.frames is better than a matrix for mixed types
ref.df <- data.frame(colonies, x_ref, y_ref)

#new data to classify
new.df<-data.frame(
  x = c(1226,1197,1208),
  y = c(6652,6593,3451)
)

#calculate pairwise distances
mydist<-as.matrix(
    dist(rbind(setNames(ref.df[,2:3], c("x","y")), 
    new.df[,1:2])))
    [-(1:nrow(ref.df)), 1:nrow(ref.df)]

#apply threshold
is.na(mydist) <- mydist>500
#define helper function to classify each match
which.max.na <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else which.min(x)
#assign new categries
newdf$colonies <- ref.df$colonies[apply(mydist,1, which.max.na)]
```

This maybe somewhat inefficient as `dist()` does all pairwise comparisons when we are only really interested in a subset. But it all depends on how large your data is really.